# Extract details info from regsubsets

Tags: r, regression

Given a dataset, if we use regsubsets function in R, we are only able to plot the result using a scale like Adjusted R Squared:

```
    data(iris)
    a = regsubsets(Petal.Width~.,data=mmat,nbest=5)
    plot(a,scale="adjr2")
```

Is there a way to have detailed information like the leap function? details such as variable "which" and "adjr2"?

```
    data(iris)
    a = leaps(x=iris[,-5], y=iris[,5], method=c("adjr2"), names=names(iris[-5]))
    print(a$which)
        print(a$adjr2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain this information by applying the `summary()` function to `regsubsets()`. This method allows for `$which`, `$rsq`, `$adjr2`, `$cp`, `$bic`, etc. to be calculated.

```
library(leaps)
data(iris)
a <- summary(regsubsets(Petal.Width~.,data=iris,nbest=5))
summary(a)
a$which
a$rsq
a$adjr2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but checking out the documentation on `regsubsets()` at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaps/leaps.pdf we can see that that function also supports `which` as well as metrics beyond adjusted r squared (e.g. Cp, r squared, BIC).

You may also find the examples here of use: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html